# Doubt related to Bernoulli's Equation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, bernoulli-equation

Can someone explain why we are taking $P_2V_2$ left side and not right side like we did with $P_1V_1$ when deriving the equation?

[image: 1]

Comment: I added a sentence if refresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is analyzing one section of flow. It is being pushed on from either side by the surrounding fluid. It is true that the fluid is flowing to the right, so the displacement is in the opposite direction of the force due to $P_2$ - the displacement is to the right. The arrow pushing left is the force from the $P_2A_2$, not the direction the fluid flows nor the direction that the $V_2$ goes. That’s why there’s a negative sign in the last line about work done $+P_1A_1V_1- P_2A_2V_2$, because the direction of the force is left and the direction of the $V_2$ coming out is right.

In particular, the kinetic energy difference is just measuring the two kinetic energies, but the gravity and pressure terms come from the total **work done** on the fluid between the two locations. That’s why the work done is negative from both gravity and pressure at point 2.